# Duplicating code based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am still trying to get to grips with VBA.

I have the following code which essentially generates a row of lottery numbers.
At the moment it provides me with 5 random numbers from 1-49 and 2 random numbers from 1-10.

I need it to make the values unique i.e none of the 5 can be duplicates and the 2 cannot be the same as each other.

Also if i was to have in Cell "A1" how many lines would you like and say in "E1" a number is entered, how could i generate the amount of lines as stated in "E1"?

```
Sub Lotto()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim I, choose, numbers(49) As Integer

Range("G2").Select
 For I = 1 To 49
  numbers(I) = I
 Next

Randomize Timer
 For I = 1 To 5
  choose = 1 + Application.Round(Rnd * (49 - I), 0)
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, I - 1).Value = numbers(choose)
    numbers(choose) = numbers(40 - I)
 Next

ActiveCell.Range("A2:N2").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=ActiveCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=True, Orientation:= _
xlLeftToRight
Range("a3").Select
ActiveCell.Select


Range("M2").Select
 For J = 1 To 10
  numbers(J) = J
 Next

Randomize Timer
 For J = 1 To 2
  choose = 1 + Application.Round(Rnd * (10 - J), 0)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, J - 1).Value = numbers(choose)
  numbers(choose) = numbers(10 - J)
 Next

 ActiveCell.Range("M2:N2").Select
 Selection.Sort Key1:=ActiveCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
 xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=True, Orientation:= _
 xlLeftToRight
 Range("a4").Select
 ActiveCell.Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Wrap a loop inside an `if` to check if number has been generated already?

Comment: Using a randbetween() function can do the job too and need not use any loops or anything

Comment: Although adding in a randbetween() wouldn't make each number unique, so would it not return the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the project called UniqueRand, and paste the code below. The idea is to create an array of unique values, randomly shuffle it, and then iterate through the array to get the next random value:

```
Private mValues() As Integer
Private mPoolSize As Integer
Private mCurrIdx As Integer
Private mRecycle As Boolean

' reuse the same sequence if true
' reshuffle the order if false
Public Property Let Recycle(rec As Boolean)
    mRecycle = rec
End Property

' Set the size of the random number pool to 1 to Size
Public Property Let Size(sz As Integer)
    mPoolSize = sz
    ReDim mValues(sz)
    ShufflePool
End Property

' return the next random value from the pool
Public Property Get NextRand() As Integer
    NextRand = mValues(mCurrIdx)
    mCurrIdx = mCurrIdx + 1
    If mCurrIdx = mPoolSize Then
        mCurrIdx = 0
        If Not mRecycle Then
            ShufflePool
        End If
    End If
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    mPoolSize = 0
    mCurrIdx = 0
    mRecycle = True
End Sub

' internal method to generate random ints from min to max
Private Function RandBetween(min As Integer, max As Integer) As Integer
    RandBetween = min + CInt(Rnd() * (max - min))
End Function

Private Sub ShufflePool()
    If mPoolSize = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 0 To mPoolSize - 1
        mValues(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    ' swap values at randomly selected index
    Dim tmp
    For i = 0 To mPoolSize - 1
        Dim idx
        idx = RandBetween(1, mPoolSize)
        tmp = mValues(i)
        mValues(i) = mValues(idx)
        mValues(idx) = tmp
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can use a separate instance of the class for each random list.
Regarding how to populate the rows from the value in E5, just reference E5 and the cells want to populate directly:

```
Sub PopulateRow()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim ur As UniqueRand
    Dim nValues As Integer
    Dim outputRow As Integer

    Set sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    nValues = sheet.Cells.Range("E5").Value

    Set ur = New UniqueRand
    ur.Size = nValues

    outputRow = 6
    For Col = 1 To nValues
        sheet.Cells(outputRow, Col).Value = ur.NextRand
    Next Col

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is over-kill :) Haven't check but if this does what the OP ask, then kudos!

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the UniqueRand ("User - defined type not defined"), no matter it gives me a much better idea of what to do!  Thanks

Comment: Apologies! You need to set the name of the class by selecting it in the project and then in the property pane enter UniqueRand for the (Name) property. Also the ShufflePool method was missing in my answer (edited). @L42: yes it's overkill but a useful approach I encountered many years ago and enjoyed the exercise of reproducing it from memory!